# Next js / React js - useReducer overload error while using with useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, next.js13

No overload matches this call.

```
  Argument of type '(state: userType, action: appReducerActionType) => { cart: (CartProductType | undefined)[]; id: string; name: string; userName: string; cartItemsCount: number; cartItemsTotalPrice: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
    Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: userType, action: appReducerActionType) => { cart: (CartProductType | undefined)[]; id: string; name: string; userName: string; cartItemsCount: number; cartItemsTotalPrice: number; }, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
  Argument of type 'userType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)
import AppReducer
```

Need suggestions. How to overcome this?

Comment: this error is a Type error, how about the result? Is it correct?

Comment: You need to provide a code snippet. The error itself tells what it is. But the code snippet will help giving you more accurate solutions